# Permutation matrix $56\times 56$

Tags: matrices

I want to find all possible permutation matrices for an identity matrix. I need it at a $56\times 56$ level. An explanation at a lower level would also help.

Comment: What do you mean, "for an identity matrix"? Do you want to count the total number of 56x56 permutation matrices? Or produce a list of such matrices? Also, please provide [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960/74908) for your question.

Answer (score 3):

The square $ n\times n$ permutation matrices are in one-to-one correspondence with elements of the symmetric group on $n$ elements. Since there are $n!$ distinct permutations, then there are $n!$ permutation matrices.

Answer (score 1):

To reinforce Laars Helenius's answer.

Suppose you have the $n \times n$ identity matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \cdots  &0  \\
0 & 1 &\cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

If we want to find all permutation matrices we can think as following:

- The $1$ in first row can be placed in $n$ positions.
- The $1$ in second row can be placed in $(n-1)$ positions.
  $$\vdots$$
- Following the same procedure, the $1$ in the last row can be placed in exactly $1$ position.

So, the number of permutations is:
$$n\cdot (n-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1=n!$$